# WebAPI and https not playing well together

Tags: https, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting errors (strange ones) when I try to do GET,PUT,POST,DELETE with https to the same WebAPI controller calls that work http.  Is there any special web.config magic that is needed for https with WebAPI controllers?

** ADDING ERROR:

(this is the error code I get when I hit the same GET web api controller as the one that works with http. that is, http works, https fails with this error)

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"A null value was returned where an instance of HttpResponseMessage was expected.","exceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","stackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ResponseMessageResultConverter.Convert(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, Object actionResult)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3.<InvokeActionAsync>b__1(Object value)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3b`2.<Then>b__3a(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"}
```

Comment: Did you enable HTTPS for your project in the properties view? If you're using IIS Express, I think you should see a "SSL Enabled" option there. Select project in solution explorer then hit F4.

Comment: Can you include the error that you're getting? That will make it much easier to help.

Comment: I'm testing on a real IIS 7.5 server with https configured correctly.  I've posted the error above.

Comment: anyone have any more thoughts on this?

Comment: there is no such attribute under System.Web.Http. So I wonder, what are you using to force https?